# iOS AudioQueue: kAudioQueueErr_InvalidPropertyValue for property kAudioQueueProperty_CurrentLevelMeter

Tags: c++, ios

I want to add a method to get the audio input signal level to the class AQRecorder.mm from the SpeakHere classes. The OSStatus instance gives me the error code corresponding to `kAudioQueueErr_InvalidPropertyValue`. I don't understand how this error can even happen because I use the predefined constant for the property. How can this be and how can I correct this error?

```
float AQRecorder::getAveragePower()
{
    assert(mQueue!=NULL);
    UInt32 expectedSize = sizeof(AudioQueueLevelMeterState);
    assert(expectedSize>0);
    AudioQueueLevelMeterState* audioLevels = (AudioQueueLevelMeterState*)malloc(sizeof(AudioQueueLevelMeterState));
    OSStatus status = AudioQueueGetProperty(mQueue,kAudioQueueProperty_CurrentLevelMeterDB, audioLevels, &expectedSize);
    if(status!=noErr)
    {
        printf("Error getting the average power: error code %i",status);
        return 0;
    }
    return audioLevels->mAveragePower;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This sounds like if you didn't activate level metering for your audioqueue yet:

```
UInt32 val = 1;
OSStatus status = AudioQueueSetProperty(mQueue, kAudioQueueProperty_EnableLevelMetering, &val, sizeof(UInt32));
if(status!=noErr)
{
    printf("Error enabling level metering\n");
}
```